# Pandas - Finding Unique Entries in Daily Census Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, data-cleaning

I have census data that looks like this for a full month and I want to find out how many unique inmates there were for the month. The information is taken daily so there are multiples.

```
  _id,Date,Gender,Race,Age at Booking,Current Age
    1,2016-06-01,M,W,32,33
    2,2016-06-01,M,B,25,27
    3,2016-06-01,M,W,31,33
```

My method now is to group them by day and then add the ones that are not accounted for into the DataFrame. My question is how to account for two people with the same info. They would both get not added to the new DataFrame because one of them already exists? I'm trying to figure out how many people total were in the prison during this time.

_id is incremental, for example here is some data from the second day

```
2323,2016-06-02,M,B,20,21
2324,2016-06-02,M,B,44,45
2325,2016-06-02,M,B,22,22
2326,2016-06-02,M,B,38,39
```

link to the dataset here: https://data.wprdc.org/dataset/allegheny-county-jail-daily-census

Comment: Is _id unique or incremental?

Comment: What constitutes a unique inmate?  Is it the combination of `'Gender', 'Race', 'Age at Booking', 'Current Age'`?  What if an inmate has a birthday and has two unique values for `'Current Age'` within a month? Is there a way to distinguish that inmate as a single inmate as opposed to two inmates?

Comment: It's the combination of 'Gender', 'Race', 'Age at Booking', 'Current Age'. That's all the information that is given. A tough spot would be if someone with the same information left on the day someone came in. I have a link to the dataset here for more info https://data.wprdc.org/dataset/allegheny-county-jail-daily-census

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `df.drop_duplicates()` which will return the DataFrame with only unique values, then count the entries.

Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('inmates_062016.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

uniqueDF = df.drop_duplicates()
countUniques = len(uniqueDF.index)
print(countUniques)
```

Result:

```
>> 11845
```

[Pandas drop_duplicates Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

[Inmates June 2016 CSV](https://data.wprdc.org/datastore/dump/869ca391-7508-4a64-8a27-09cc4799923f)

The problem with this approach / data is that there could be many individual inmates that are the same age / gender / race that would be filtered out.

Comment: I'm going through like 10 months that each have around 50,000 records. I would do it manually if I have too, but was looking for a savvier way.

Comment: Updated, try the above code to see if that is more like what you would want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick here is to groupby as much as possible and check the differences in those (small) groups through the month:

```
inmates = pd.read_csv('inmates.csv')

# group by everything except _id and count number of entries
grouped = inmates.groupby(
    ['Gender', 'Race', 'Age at Booking', 'Current Age', 'Date']).count()

# pivot the dates out and transpose - this give us the number of each
# combination for each day
grouped = grouped.unstack().T.fillna(0)

# get the difference between each day of the month - the assumption here
# being that a negative number means someone left, 0 means that nothing
# has changed and positive means that someone new has come in. As you
# mentioned yourself, that isn't necessarily true
diffed = grouped.diff()

# replace the first day of the month with the grouped numbers to give
# the number in each group at the start of the month
diffed.iloc[0, :] = grouped.iloc[0, :]

# sum only the positive numbers in each row to count those that have
# arrived but ignore those that have left
diffed['total'] = diffed.apply(lambda x: x[x > 0].sum(), axis=1)

# sum total column
diffed['total'].sum()  # 3393
```